# Can the Spring Cloud AWS SQS ON_SUCCESS deletion policy create an infinite loop? Or does i t have retries?

Tags: amazon-sqs, retry-logic, spring-cloud-aws

I want to retry failed messages in my Spring Cloud SQS listener with something like:

```
@SqsListener(value = [QUEUE_NAME], deletionPolicy = ON_SUCCESS)
fun read(message: MyEvent) {
```

But I am worried that if one specific event causes a deterministic failure it could end in an infinite loop.

Does it have any kind of retry policy protecting against an infinite loop?